# Cases of using an article before the gerund

Tags: articles, definite-article, gerunds

I found an example of using "the" before the gerund:

> During **the** crossing the passengers felt the ship toss

But according to the grammar, no article is used before the gerund.
Or in this case ***the crossing*** isn't the gerund?

Comment: "The crossing" is a noun phrase as object complement of the preposition "during". What makes you think it's a gerund?

Comment: What are your sources to "the grammar" ? As other said, this is a noun, not a gerund.

Comment: It’s the noun form of the verb “to cross”. I believe that makes it a gerund, even though it’s part of a noun phrase or prepositional phrase. Doesn’t it?

Comment: You’d still say “The crossing proved to be dangerous,” even though there are no prepositions involved in that sentence.

Comment: A gerund is something that works like a verb with its words. For example "the crossing from A to B", here crossing works as a noun, compare with "the way from A to B". And "crossing the channel", here it _governs_ as a verb, "to cross the channel". Note how you never can put a real noun in this phrase, e.g. "way the channel", makes no sense. Here crossing is a gerund.

Answer (score 7):

Gerunds act like any other noun and can take the definite or indefinite article when referring to a specific instance of an activity:

> a reading of my latest book
>
> the singing coming from the church

The rule you’re citing is that the gerund does not take the definite article when referring to an activity in general, but this rule also applies in other cases where the noun isn’t a gerund:

> I like swimming.
>
> I like basketball.

I suspect this rule is taught because it’s explicitly different from many Romance languages, where the definite article is used to refer to general activities.

Comment: +1 I am surprised this answer hasn't got any upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

'Ing' structure can be used as a noun.

> The smoking
>   The meeting
>   The coding

If you want more information, check this [link](https://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/ingform/menu.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from Cambridge Dictionary.

On page https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tick you can see "the ticking" in the definition of verb "tick".

> The ticking of the clock kept her awake.